# cocoapods framework not found

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoapods

I'm getting framework not found error when running my workspace with cocoa pod.

> ld: framework not found AFNetworking
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm looking in my build settings and I have $(inherited) set as the framework search path. Is that where cocoa pad generates the framework files?

here's my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '7.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'workouttracker' do

  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
  pod 'ORStackView', '~> 2.0'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.1'
  pod "MagicalRecord"

end

target 'WorkoutTrackerTests' do


end

target 'workouttracker WatchKit Extension' do

  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
  pod 'ORStackView', '~> 2.0'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.1'
  pod "MagicalRecord"

end

target 'workouttracker WatchKit App' do

  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
  pod 'ORStackView', '~> 2.0'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.1'
  pod "MagicalRecord"

end
```

Comment: Anything on this? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

This is a linking issue. 
What does your `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` & `OTHER_LDFLAGS` look like in the Build Target? Make sure to use the `$(inherited)` flag. You might see that warning as the output during `pod install`.